# Caching images with asp/http

Tags: http, asp-classic, browser-cache

I want to cache all the images on my site, so I used this code:

```
<%Response.AddHeader "Expires","Tue, 2 October 2013 00:00:00 GMT"%>
```

The problem is that google says the images are not cached, whenever I go to this site:

```
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed
```

Also in chrome, I can see that it gives a Get response for all the images.

Why is that and how can I cache the images for the next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have cached the page itself (which might also be a good thing though), rather than the images within. In order to cache images, you should set appropriate settings in IIS or your .config file(s).

Have a look at these:

- http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache
- http://www.galcho.com/Blog/post/2008/02/27/IIS7-How-to-set-cache-control-for-static-content.aspx